# Trouble sending RTP packets to VLC client from java RTSP server

Tags: java, rtsp, rtp

I'm currently extending this project http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html to implement a very basic RTSP server.

So far I've got a crude multi-threaded implementation hard coded to respond to OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP and PLAY requests using VLC player as a client. The problem is after responding to the PLAY request, VLC does not seem to acknowledge any RTP packets sent on the port number it specified in the SETUP request. When output, the relevant part of my SETUP response -

```
RTSPBufferedWriter.write("Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port="
                    + RTP_dest_port + "-" + (RTP_dest_port + 1)
                    + ";server_port=55556-55557" + CRLF);
```

the RTP_dest_port matches the client request. The UDP initialisation is then as follows;

```
 RTPsocket = new DatagramSocket(55556);
```

...

```
senddp = new DatagramPacket(packet_bits, packet_length, ClientIPAddr, RTP_dest_port);  
RTPsocket.send(senddp);
```

However packets never seems to reach the client as there is no video output and it eventually gives this error.

```
live555 warning: no data received in 10s. Switching to TCP
```

before switching to RTP over TCP mode.

I'm not certain if the UDP initialisation is wrong or if it is receiving malformed RTP packets but just not registering them as mjpeg data. Any advice as to what exactly is happening here would be much obliged!

Just for additional information I'm testing this using localhost, retrieving the ClientIPAddr from the TCP socket and not yet handling RTCP.

Comment: have you resolved this issue? what is your vlc rtsp://yoururl -vvv output?